# Why does it take four or five refreshes to get my API images/objects to get on the screen? (Jquery/HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

*bit* of a newbie here.

I'm writing a search function where it loads all carousel images based off an api to my database. I'm using [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html) for the carousel.

So... 
To begin with, it boots up with 'all', sort of thing.

Then when you enter keys *into* the input, it filters and should re-render the carousel images based on the filtered down array of objects.

So issues:-

1) When i first load localhost:3000, it takes five or six page refreshes before the images show. So is HTML loading before its data is ready?

2) When i input a search, it *does* filter correctly, & when i create a new set of elements with the exact same class/id names and *change* the html to those, i get nothing showing on screen.

NOTE: I suspect this is the same issue as having to refresh the page loads of times at boot-up. Except i *can't* refresh the page as that would clear the search and take me back to 'all'.

So what am i missing here? *What* do you put into the jquery/javascript to ensure the HTML waits for Jquery to finish creating elements, appending them to a new, re-created div etc? Or is there some way of putting everything in order to ensure the correct flow happens?

**HTML:**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="carouselId" class="carousel">

   // carousel items in here are. Docs say they each 'tile' should be like this:

        <a class="carousel-item" href="#linktoSomewhere">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1">
        </a>
</div>
</body>
```

The Entire HTML Head and upper Body section looks like this:[image: link to image]

**Javascript/Jquery**:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('carouselId');
var searchTerm;

$(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#searchBoxText').on('input', function(e) {
    searchTerm = e.target.value;
    populateCarousel();
  });

});

function populateCarousel() {
  var moviesArray = [];
  var tempResultsArr = [];

  fetch('http://localhost:3000/getdata')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      moviesArray = json;

      if (typeof searchTerm === 'undefined') {
        moviesArray.map((each) => {

          var eachTile = document.createElement("a");
          var imageForEachTile = document.createElement("img");
          imageForEachTile.setAttribute('src', each.poster);
          eachTile.setAttribute("class", "carousel-item thumbnail-item");
          eachTile.setAttribute("href", "#linkToSomeWhere");
          eachTile.innerHTML = each.title;
          eachTile.appendChild(imageForEachTile);
          wrapper.appendChild(eachTile);
        })

      } else {

        // as soon as you type, you nuke the existing html.
        $('#carouselId').html('');

        // function that filters api down to relevant objects/results
        function checkWords(st, arr) {
            let term = st.toLowerCase();
            return arr.filter(each => each.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) === 0);
        }

        // place search results in 'filteredArray'
        let filteredArray = checkWords(searchTerm, moviesArray);

        // creating a whole new wrapper and carousel component
        // to replace the nuked one.
        let newWrapper = document.createElement('div')
        newWrapper.setAttribute('id', 'carouselId');
        newWrapper.setAttribute('class', 'carousel');

        // map through the array and create a new image and attribute
        // tag for each, to append to the *NEW* carousel wrpaper.
        filteredArray.map((each) => {
          var eachTile = document.createElement('a');
          var imageForEachTile = document.createElement('img');
          imageForEachTile.setAttribute('src', each.poster);
          eachTile.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-item thumbnail-item');
          eachTile.setAttribute('href', '#linkToSomeWhere');
          eachTile.innerHTML = each.title;
          eachTile.appendChild(imageForEachTile);
          newWrapper.appendChild(eachTile);
        })

        // newWrapper logs out correct info
        console.log('newWrapper: ', newWrapper);
        $(wrapper).html(newWrapper);
        // ^^ html is assigned correctly, inspect-element shows
        // correct results in place, but no results on screen.

      }
    })
}

populateCarousel();
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer to set all of my css files in the header like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>[A USEFULL TITLE]</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/screen.css">
```

And I always place all my JS file under the body like this:

```
</body>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/sriptForLocalGraphs.js"></script>
</html>
```

I do my JS this to make sure he excute the code when the document is ready:

```
var init = function () {
DoSomeFunctions();
};
$(document).ready(init());
```

What I also prefer is to make a String that I append in the HTML at once not adding a piece evertime:

Like this for example:

```
var createAForm = function(SomeHandyData){
    var $resultaatString = "";
    $.each(SomeHandyData, function (index, item) {
$resultaatString + = <img id='localImage' class='media-object' src='assets/media/" + longName + ".png' alt='" + longName + "' title='" + longName + "'>
});

    $("#InAELEMENTDIV").html($resultaatString);
};
```